# Terraform installing a provider when it isn't needed

Tags: terraform, apple-m1

Due to using an M1 mac, I am receiving an error that is preventing a successful terraform init (see below); this is caused by terraform trying to install the hasicorp/template provider when it isn't needed.  Why is the hashicorp/template provider trying to install when there aren't any resources requiring it?

> │ Error: Incompatible provider version │  │ Provider
> registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0 does not have a
> package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.

This is documented here: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/template-v2-2-0-does-not-have-a-package-available-mac-m1/35099

Specifically, terraform keeps trying to install the hashicorp/template provider even though I'm not using template_file or any other entity from that provider; I tried deleting .terraform and my lock file and still I have this issue:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/template...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the statefile was still referencing a template_file object.  I removed it via `terraform state rm <object>`, which now allows a successful terraform init.

Comment: Quick command to remove reference from state file after replacing template_file with templatefile and template_cloudinit_config with cloudinit_config if both or either is used.

`terraform state list | grep -E -i -w 'template_file|template_cloudinit_config' | xargs terraform state rm`

**The above works for states stored locally or in cloud.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than remove the reference from the state file directly. darwin_arm64 terraform seemingly contains some bug which is not ignoring empty instance records of plugins when running `terraform init`. e.g.:

```
 {
   "module": "module.region_0",
   "mode": "data",
   "type": "template_file",
   "name": "cloudwatch_agent_update_document",
   "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template\"]",
   "instances": []
 },
```

This is not listed in `terraform state list` so you can't remove it cleanly. The only option is to download your state file remove these blocks and push the state file back. I don't know if this error is tracked anywhere already so if someone knows that it is not, please raise it in Hashicorp forums (ideally some enterprise user).